# Enhanced Session Mode not working - Hyper-V Guest

Tags: 18.04, windows, virtualization, hyper-v

I created a Ubuntu VM using "Quick Create" on a separate Windows installation. I have since moved the disk a few times and run a bunch of commands on it and somehow I can't get enhanced session to work.

I have ran the following in the VM:

```
cat << 'EOF' >~/setup_enhanced_session_hv_mods.sh
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt purge -y linux-azure
sudo apt autoremove -y --purge
sudo apt install -y linux-azure
update-initramfs -u
reboot
EOF
chmod +x ~/setup_enhanced_session_hv_mods.sh
~/setup_enhanced_session_hv_mods.sh
```

`lsmod` shows this:

```
root@skynet:~# lsmod | grep hv
hv_balloon             28672  0
hv_sock                16384  1
vsock                  36864  2 hv_sock
hv_netvsc              73728  0
hv_storvsc             20480  5
scsi_transport_fc      57344  1 hv_storvsc
hv_utils               32768  0
hv_vmbus               94208  8 hv_balloon,hv_utils,hv_netvsc,hid_hyperv,hv_storvsc,hyperv_keyboard,hv_sock,hyperv_fb
```

`uname`:

```
root@skynet:~# uname -r
5.3.0-40-generic
```

And this on the host:

```
Set-VM -VMName SkyNet -EnhancedSessionTransportType HvSocket
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little scary how I did it, since auto-remove didn't seem to work. I deleted all the kernels under boot, downloaded linux-azure deb, installed via dpkg, updated initramfs & grub. Powered off and upon boot got it working again!